# Make a Group Shape appear/disapear based on Input

Tags: vba, excel

If the input in "C18" is 1, Group 1/2/3/4 (groups of lines) should disappear. Doesn't happen.

Code:

```
    Private Sub Design_Click()

    Dim TorsionGroup As ShapeRange
    Dim Toption As Integer

    Set Toption = Range("C18")

    Set TorsionGroup = Shapes.Range(Array("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3", "Group 4"))

    If Toption = 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.TorsionGroup.GroupItems().Visible = False
    Else
        ActiveSheet.TorsionGroup.GroupItems().Visible = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: it should be `TorsionGroup.Visible` instead of `ActiveSheet.TorsionGroup.GroupItems().Visible`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Sub Design_Click()
    Shapes.Range(["Group "&column(a:d)]).Visible = [C18] = 1
End Sub
```

or if you group the groups into a single group, just:

```
Public Sub Design_Click()
    [Group 5].Visible = [C18] = 1
End Sub
```